# amazon app store and android licensing LVL

Tags: android, licensing, amazon-appstore

So, I have a few little android apps now, and am thinking about releasing the in the Amazon App Store.  However I have one fundamental question I don't see answered anywhere.

How is Licensing handled if you release the app on the amazon store?  I am currently using the Google LVL licensing in my paid apps to ensure the user is licensed to run them.  I assume that an app sold on Amazon, isn't going to have any connection to tell Google, hey, this app was purchased, they are licensed, so send them an OK TO RUN status when they launch it. Or am I mistaken?

Does Amazon have its own LVL type code? Or do you just have to forget licensing all together if you want to sell on Amazon?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works but I'm positive that Amazon does allow licensing for apps. When my Droid X got the update to Gingerbread I wasn't able to use any apps I downloaded from amazon until I logged in to the App Store to confirm my license.  You get a message like [this](http://cdn.androidcommunity.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/amazon-android-error-540x403.jpg) if you try to run the app without confirmation that you've paid for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143033/in-app-payment-in-amazon @theisenp

Answer (score 10):

Simply remove all LVL code from your app (making it unprotected), then select the copy protection radio button when submitting your app to Amazon.  They'll add the licensing code to your app before resigning it and releasing it on the Amazon Appstore.

No store-provided licensing code works in other app stores.  Many have rolled their own, with varying degrees of simplicity.

Comment: You don't have to remove all the LVL code, just disable it. If you use dependency injection (i.e. Roboguice/Guice) you can simply point to a different module during your build process for Amazon that has an implementation of your license service code that does nothing (or something if Amazon were to have a licensing library we could use).

Comment: Hi, can you clear me about where can I find this "the copy protection radio button when submitting your app to Amazon" Please. I just searched all the "MyApps" section but in vain. Just provide where to find that Radio Button.

Comment: The current spot on Amazon is under the "Binary File(s)" tab.  There's an option for "Apply Amazon DRM?".  And yes to Christopher's comment - if the DRM code for other app stores is inert and won't be run, it likely won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 6):

> I have an app in Android Market. What should I do to ensure the app
> works in the Amazon Appstore?
>
> You should make sure that your app does
> not include any copy protection functionality (you have the option to
> apply Amazon’s DRM technology – see our FAQ on DRM). You should also
> take a moment to understand the different signing options available to
> you (developer signed or Amazon signed) and choose the option that
> works best for your users.

[Source](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html;#Support%20and%20Troubleshooting)